# Opening UDP ports in iPad/iPhone firewall

Tags: ios, firewall, netbios

I'm trying to implement NetBIOS discovery on an iOS device, but it seems that the NetBIOS ports (137, 138) are blocked by the iOS. Is there a programmatic way to open a UDP/TCP port in the firewall on an iOS device? Thanks!

Comment: Just listen on those ports inside of an iOS app that you make. There is no firewall; the device just isn't listening to those ports. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/CH73-SW9

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Also, there are probably easier ways to listen to ports than the examples in the Apple documentation. I've seen a few decent ones here on StackOverflow.